# What is that colorful plate puzzle?

Tags: puzzle-identification, mechanical-puzzles

There was this colorful puzzle I remember playing with almost 8 years ago. It was consisted of a number of different colored plates (green, purple, blue), that, connected to each other by hinges, can be made into a number of different 3D shapes and figures. It had somewhere between 6-8 plates, the unhinged edges of which could be locked with other edges to hold the form of the puzzle.

Not sure if this is enough clear detail, but can anyone identify the puzzle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it could be [Cubigami 7 by Recent Toys](https://www.recenttoys.com/recent-toys-cumigami-7/), though it has quite a few more plates than you remember.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ooh!  I've been looking for something like this, only I'd want a set that has other regular polygons as well, from 3 to 10 sides.  (I want to make my own set of the Archimedean Solids, maybe the Johnson Solids when I'm done with those.  I've done them in paper, but would prefer something a little more durable.)  Not sure I'd call this a "puzzle" though, more of just a construction kit, unless some of the joints can't be separated?  That might add some puzzling aspects to it...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Yes, on this puzzle there are fixed hinges, so it forms a net which can fold into various shapes. For separate tiles that you can connect together, take a look at [Polydron sets](https://www.polydron.co.uk/mathematics.html).

Comment: Hmm, they even have an Archimedean set - little pricey though, maybe I'll put it on my wish list for future purchases.  Thanks for the link though, it's at least a good baseline for comparison.